# MD5 acting different in SQL database and in PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, md5, cryptographic-hash-function

Recently I have created a script that handles login and register for my Game that uses http_get method to update stats. I have managed to create everything successfully, but there is a problem. When a user registers, it inserts different md5 string that PHP scripts generated and because of this, I cannot compare passwords.

This is the way I insert md5 string into a database:

```
$pw = md5($password);
    $insert = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO Accounts (username, password, email,reg_ip, wins, looses, experience) VALUES ('$username', '$pw', '$email',  '$reg_ip', '0','0', '0')");
    if($insert) {
            echo "account successfully created"; 

        } 
        else {
            echo "error";
        }
```

And this is the way I check for passwords:

```
if($p['password'] == md5($password)) {
                echo "login was successful!";
            }
            else {
                echo "incorrect password";
            }
```

This is the md5 string that is in the database when user registers: (un-encrypted string is: pocakaj123)

```
54e8850ba5eca655854ddf1b503943
```

and this is the generated string when I `echo md5($password)`.

```
54e8850ba5eca655854ddf1b50394348
```

Comment: Why is one of them only 30 characters?  Hex for an MD5 is 32 characters.

Comment: You shouldn't use `md5` to store your passwords anyway so this problem is irrelevant.

Comment: See: [How to safely store your users' passwords](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016).

Comment: With PHP use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), the pair are secure and easy to use. When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead  use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions with about a 100ms duration. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 6):

This is due to the length of your field in your database. You need to increase the length so that the whole string can fit.

Currently, it only accepts 30 characters so the remaining gets truncated:

```
54e8850ba5eca655854ddf1b503943
```

You need to increase the length to at least 32 to fit the whole string:

```
54e8850ba5eca655854ddf1b50394348
```

---

**Note:**

`md5()` is not a secure way to hash passwords, a better way is `bcrypt()` or instead use PHP's password hashing functions, `password_hash()`.

Reason that `md5()` is not secure:

> Hashing algorithms such as MD5, SHA1 and SHA256 are designed to be very fast and efficient. With modern techniques and computer equipment, it has become trivial to "brute force" the output of these algorithms, in order to determine the original input.

Referenced from http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's also important to note, though, that this is *not* a secure way to store passwords. MD5 is broken. OP should be using bcrypt, not rolling his own hashing solution.

Comment: @EdCottrell True, will update post to add this tip, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @BorutMatjasic Maybe accept this answer if it helped you? Thanks!